# Bootstrap menu items all on the same row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, web-frontend

I have a problem with my navigation bar. I want all of my items to be in the same row, I can not find the problem, why is the last one on the second row?

Here is the code:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12 nav-wrap">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li><a href="index.html" class="page-scroll">Acasa</a></li>
```

And this is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: send code in fiddle

Comment: show us all your html + css, if you have js in this page, that too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is just because you have a class collapse navbar-collapse text-center because of text-center property your 1st element aligned as centered and onwards. remove text center from the class of your div

Comment: unfortunately this approach does not work, it still looks the same

Answer (score 0):

the answer is this: remove the nav-wrap from div.

thank you all!